# Newbie trying to install Ubuntu - need some help, thanks!

Tags: system-installation

I'm not hugely tech savvy but I'm trying to be....hence trying to install and use Ubuntu. I have a Thinkpad T400 Intel Core duo 2.53 GHz 160Gb hdd windows XP which I picked up from eBay to install Ubuntu. I'm trying to install 19.10 from CD/DVD as the XP Windows IE cannot support/download anything at all to the USB/flashdrive. Anyway, I seemed to get quite far through the process when suddenly a load of error messages related to a TPM chip(?) appeared. Shortly after the disc simply ejected. I have no idea what any of this means....can anyone help? And please I'd appreciate it if you talked to me like I am a five year old!!! Thank you very much in advance!

Regards,
S

Comment: Clearing the TPM (Trusted Platform Module) resets the TPM to an unowned state. It's something you would do if you were selling your laptop to another person. If you don't want XP, formatting the disk will give an option to trash the TPM providing better options.

Comment: Thank you very much! One final question....maybe an obvious one, apologies,....but how would I do this? Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: @Stuart Do you have another computer? Download ubuntu, burn the ISO to a USB drive, boot from that drive, and then format the PC and install Ubuntu. Also, since your computer is older I would suggest installing Xubuntu or Lubuntu as they are lighter and work better with older computers. Running ubuntu on your pc might be slow

Comment: Thank you both. I have a MacBook Air but can I download the 64 bit version of Lubuntu to a USB stick via my Mac then boot the Thinkpad from the USB? As you can see......I'm trying lol!